# Newsletter change hypertext

Tags: android, html, ios, email, newsletter

I'm trying to make a responsive e-mail. I got everything about design, but one question stand for me.

I would make a link on a picture, going on my website if user is on a computer, and going to App store if he's on iOS, going on android market if he's on Android phone.

One picture, but 3 different link for 3 different users, is that possible ?

Thanks a lot, and pardon my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, very much possible. Try something like this

```
 <a href="http://www.microsoft.com" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('http://www.example1.com'); window.open('http://www.example2.com');">
 Your Image
 </a>
```

That way which ever device will only open the applicable webpage or application.

Comment: Theoretically, it will redirect to the links you include... given that they are applicable to the specific device.